# Goldfish-unknown white marks

Tags: health, goldfish

[image]I’m really concerned about one of my goldfish as this morning I noticed 2 marks on his body. One near the head and one near the tail. I noticed my bigger goldfish nudging him out of the way at feeding time so I’m unsure if it’s bullying or a water issue. I’ve googled a lot and can’t find a definite answer Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Can you indicate by arrows where the marks are, and what type of goldfish this is? Some get fleshy growths as part of the breed.